# What would be a simple aerodynamics simulation software for a student?

Tags: aerodynamics, lift, glider, flight-simulator

I have a project due 2 weeks from now that demands we make a glider using Styrofoam. I'd like to simulate the results as I plan my glider before I build it.

Which simple software, which allows importing a 3D model to do the testing on, can give me data on

- CG,
- CL,
- lift,
- drag and
- reach

based on initial velocity, etc.?

Comment: What kind of a project is this? What is your level of knowledge? High school, university? It'll help us answer your question if we know what you know already.

Comment: Welcome to SE! The characteristics you ask for are somewhat disparate: $C_L $and such indicate an airfoil analysis program, while range is a higher level performance metric dependent on more factors that just aerodynamics. Also, 3D aerodynamics is a significant step up from 2D, to the point of open source versus proprietary answers. I suggest you narrow down your question, or it may be closed as overly-broad.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is about a resource location as stated in the [help center](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "...it's not about…Where to buy a specific part, "Which headset is the best?", Where can I get a feed of flight-related data? etc."

Comment: @ROIMaison, my level of knowledge is quite limited, I've read half of Understanding Flight in a rush for a test but that's about it. It's for my first semester of college. We are building a glider and each team will fly theirs in a closed area.

Comment: @AEhere, thank you. I'm sorry for the broadness, I'm a total newbie. Since we're building a real glider I guess it'd be 3D...? I'm a bit lost haha.

Answer (score 2):

If you have only two weeks it may be best not to go running into a maze, but you may wish to have simple and complex approaches running side by side.

As others have said, it would be helpful to know the parameters of your assignment.  Are they interested in the theory, or do they want to see something flying?

The most important thing will be the airfoil shape as far as lift and drag, but glider airfoils are easily obtained on the Net (airfoil tools). Next would be wing loading, which can be obtained from existing models and data from birds.  Design can be your choice, but starting from scratch, a standard sailplane planform will serve well.

Remember to have your CG near your Clift, slightly forward, and your elevator trim slightly up. For an indoor free flight glider a high aspect wing with some dihedral and an upright vertical stabilizer will help make it fly straight.

Although the theory behind gliders is well known, getting one to fly right will be a learning curve from scratch. Leave at least 2 days for test flights, and plan on extra Styrofoam and glue for repairs. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Robert! Thank you so much for your answer, it helped a lot. As for the parameters, they want to see it fly. There will be no wind, it has to have a max. wingspan of 40cm, max weight of 30g and the initial velocity will be around 7 m/s. It's a university assignment, I'm in my first year.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the original and a bit too-broad question:

Look into [XFLR5](http://www.xflr5.com/xflr5.htm), a basic design program that does airfoil design and analysis, and can do some more advanced computations such as stability and eigenvalues. It is mostly useful for glider model design, but can be generalized if you know what you are doing.

Comment: Hi AEhere, that's what I was looking for. Thank you! I'm checking it out right now. Sorry for the broad question, I'm in my first year of college and am still learning

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to approach this.  For the bounding I suspect you want, one might try Simulink, which has a model for the DHC-2 and the Cessna 208.  In 2004 I used the model for the Caravan (208) and built some good models very quickly.  Simulink runs with MATLAB.

The Simulink toolkit which the DHC-2 and Cessna 208 models are built upon,  handles **flight dynamics and control**.

Since 2004, my usage of the above has only been situational and sporadic, but you may find a user group or some such group which can help you kickstart your design effort.

Comment: Hey mongo, thank you for the answer. I had seen Simulink before, but didn't know if it was a good idea to try it for a beginner. I got it and am messing around with it, seems to fit the needs. I'll also check out the ones the other answers provided later. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A professional software is this: http://darcorp.com/Software/AAA/

From the website:

> Advanced Aircraft Analysis (AAA) is a comprehensive airplane design program that gives its users full authority over the entire preliminary design process. From weight and performance sizing to aerodynamics and stability and control analysis, you can monitor all aspects of the design every step of the way.

What you seem to want to do is analyze an airplane before you actually designed it though.

Comment: Hey jjack, thanks for the answer. I'll definetly check it out, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: @VictorSCS But ask if it'll do styrofoam gliders. A lot of the equations are for big planes.

Comment: @jjack will do!!